# MFC custom CEdit password support

Tags: c++, mfc, cedit

I'm having a little trouble making a custom CEdit class i have added most and gave it some style but hit a stump i have googled most of the day with no luck guess Google hates me today.

OK so i have inherited the class CEdit

i have rewrote the OnPaint part to style it but i have this class applied to a password field when i update the text it shows plain password and not the **** sorry if i didnt explain correctly but only being doing this 4 days :).

here is my code i properly have stuff in there i dont need but im pretty tired and give up :)

http://pastebin.com/yegsh7E3

If anyone can help please do :)

Thanks
Dave

Answer (score 1):

No need to customize the control, just give it the style [`ES_PASSWORD`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb775464%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). I'm sure you can set the style from the resource editor too if it's in a dialog.

Comment: i do not mean that i mean completely styled i set ES_PASSWORD already but i want a total customized look

Answer (score 0):

OK i managed to sort it myself using ON_WM_PAINT and ON_WM_CTLCOLOR_REFLECT it handles them perfect now but thanks for trying to help